# UIView created in code only draws in portrait mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a view to my controller, which is put into landscape mode programmatically with the follwoing code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //EpisodeView *nextEpisode = [self getNextEpisode];
    UIImageView *nextEpisode = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"default-background.png"]];
    CGRect selfBounds = self.view.bounds;

    nextEpisode.frame = selfBounds;

    [self.view addSubview:nextEpisode]; 
}
```

The problem is that the added view draws itself in portrait mode, not in landscape. Can anyone please point out what I could have missed?
When I'm adding the same view using Interface Builder, all works perfectly fine. So, I think, I have missed some property or something like that.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code. But you have a memory leak in your code. Release your nextEpisode ImageView. ;-)

Comment: Yep, have already noticed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably haven't added `autoresizingMasks` which are by default `UIViewAutoresizingNone`.  IB has different defaults. Set them as needed.

Comment: nextEpisode.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight worked. Thank you! May be there is sense to set other flags as well.